# Css material Angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the css of Material Angular.
I want use a select component but the component is very heigth and i don't know how i can modified that.

```
 <div class="searchBar">
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>Agences</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="filterBar" multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{filterBar.value ? filterBar.value[0] : ''}}
          <span *ngIf="filterBar.value?.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
            (+{{filterBar.value.length - 1}} {{filterBar.value?.length === 2 ? 'autre' : 'autres'}})
          </span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let agence of agenceList" [value]="agence">{{agence}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

[> Picture of the material <](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6skVh.png)

when I select the element in the devTools the component that takes the most space, it is this one

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-c4 appearance="standard" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c10-0 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-select mat-form-field-appearance-standard mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched mat-form-field-hide-placeholder" ng-reflect-appearance="standard">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use scss, you can select the element with the above rule.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field {}
```

and there you can add the properties you cant to change,

Comment: unsuccessfully :/

Comment: just tested the above code and it works.
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field {
    max-height:30px;
}

if you have a component example.component.ts
and as a file for style got a example.component.scss

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to put this on and it works.

```
    min-height: 10.5;
    max-height: 10.5;
```

But if I put this on, it's not 1.5em, it's more like 3em.

```
    min-height: 1.5em;
    max-height: 1.5em;
```

Is it normal that the component can't shrink more than that?